# Is it ok to present Navigation Controller over another Navigation Controller?

Tags: ios, navigation

I have 4 viewcontrollers. A , B , C , D .

Each of them have its own navA , navB , navC , navD.

And its 4 clusters on the storyboard.

(navA --> A) (navB --> B) (navC --> C) (navD --> D)

Non of them connected to another cluster.
Each of them have "buttons" IBAction to trigger and go to another cluster.
Assume clusterA is a start point , i want to  presentViewController[navB]

this is what inside -(IBAction) gotoCVCNav

```
  UIStoryboard* sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
  UINavigationController* nav = [sb     instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"cvcNav"];
  [self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion: nil];
```

Problem is this approch lead to this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMSYL.jpg

I wonder whats a correct way to present B viewcontroller and remove A viewcontroller from memory properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use only one **navigation controller** with your **first controller** and then connect all other **controllers with segue** .**Navigation controller** keeps controllers in form of **stack** so no need of multiple navigation controller unless there is any such requirement.Now to present **B controller** you just need to **add segue to B and select PRESENT/SHOW option** . And to go back **from B to A** you can either **POP** a view controller or **DISMISS** a view controller . If you **POP a controller** it is **removed from stack** and if you **dismiss a controller** it just go behind **controller A**.

Answer (score 1):

In this specific scenario (which is very common and represents most scenarios in the real world) you do not need multiple navigation controllers.

Sometimes, you will need to add a UINavigationController on top of another one, but this is currently not the case, so I will not go into detail over that bit.

What you are doing is fundamentally having 4 differents "ways" in your app. But essentially, you need one way with 4 steps.

So instead of doing

```
(navA --> A) (navB --> B) (navC --> C) (navD --> D)
```

What you want to do is

```
Nav  ->  A (root of Nav)  ->  B  ->  C  ->  D
```

I see you are using Storyboard, which makes it easier.

Drag & drop using Right clic (or Ctrl + clic) to connect controller A to controller B in storyboard. Do the same for B -> C and C -> D.

You will see links appear. You can clic on them to rename them, give them relevant names. Those are called *segue*.

I usually name them "FromXXXToYYYY" using feature names. like "FromContactsToDetail"

You *can* (but don't have to) link from `UIViewController` to `UIViewController`, using the little yellow circle icon in storyboard, or simply by draggin on top of the controller. But you *can* also drag from a `UIButton` to a `UIViewController`. Just do the same connection (drag with right clic or drag with ctrl + clic) by starting from a UIButton.

The only difference is that if you drag from the button, the button will perform the action. If you drag from the controller, you have to type it in code manually. Sometimes you only need to do it from button, sometimes not.

If you do it with the button, your work is done.

If you do it from storyboard, you will need to call

`PerformSegue(self, "SegueNameYouEnteredInStoryboard")`.

you can call this in your `IBAction`.

If you only do a `performSegue` in the IBAction, that's maybe a sign to remove the IBAction and use the storyboard connection only.

iOS will manage the nav bar, back button and all of that for you.

Also, to answer your specific question :

> I wonder whats a correct way to present B viewcontroller and remove A viewcontroller from memory properly.

If you want to navigate back to A, you need it in memory. Just follow instructions in my answer.
If you do *not* need to go back to that controller, usually you would follow another architecture.

What you would do is have your Nav controller with your root as B. And because A is only temporary (maybe it's a login screen for example), you would load it *modally* on top of A, only if the user is logged off, for example.

Doing so is easy, just instantiate your UIViewController and present it using `presentViewController`.

Note that you *can* present a UINavigationController if, for example, your login process is made of several screens. The whole navigation would be on top of the root navigation, the user would be able to go back and forth in the login, and when its all over, you just call `dismissViewController` on the navigationcontroller to remove it, and *all* the controllers inside the stack of navigation will be removed. In my example, all the login screens will be cleared, and finally you Navigation with the controller 'B' that you had in root will be visible.

So if this is a similar situation that you have, and A is just temporary but B is your important content, then you should have your B already under A, A being visible and topmost, then just dismiss A when necessary and B will appear.